# How to do not print something under condition?

Tags: table-of-contents, conditionals

So, I have the file `backmatter.tex`

```
\clearpage
\printindex
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\indexname}

\newpage
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Перелік ілюстрацій}

\newpage
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Перелік таблиць}

\clearpage
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{bibliography}
```

This file is included at very end of main document (right before `\end{document}`).
If I use no tables in my document, it produces the title for list of tables but no table entries obviously. So I could just remove this fragment of code but doing it everytime as I do not use something would be... ...not convenient.

So, for example, how to prevent

```
\newpage
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Перелік таблиць}
```

from typesetting if there are no tables in my document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tocbibind` to avoid problems in the page number. I also define conditionals for deciding whether a table or a figure was indeed present in the document; such code *must* go in the preamble.

Using the value of the counters is not safe, because the counters might be tied to `chapter` and if there's no figure or table in the last chapter, the value is useless.

For the index, I suggest `imakeidx` that takes care of the inclusion in the table of contents. Using Xindy and not Makeindex is necessary for Cyrillic based documents.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}

\makeindex[intoc,options=-L ukrainian -C utf8]

% conditional printing of lists
\newif\iffigures
\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{%
  \iffigures\else\global\figurestrue\fi
}
\newif\iftables
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
  \iftables\else\global\tablestrue\fi
}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Спочатку}

\index{Спочатку}

\begin{figure}\caption{підпис}\end{figure}
\begin{table}\caption{підпис}\end{table}

\backmatter

\printindex

\iffigures\listoffigures\fi

\iftables\listoftables\fi

\end{document}
```

I typeset the document four times, suitably commenting or uncommenting the lines for `figure` and `table`.

##### No figures, no tables

[image]

##### Figures, no tables

[image]

##### No figures, tables

[image]

##### Figures, tables

[image]

Comment: Oh, that works exactly as I planned it to be, thank You!

Answer (score 1):

See package [tocbibind](https://ctan.org/pkg/tocbibind):

"The tocbibind package can be used to add document elements like a
bibliography or an index to the Table of Contents."

Comment: Hmm. I have read documentation, can't get the point how to use it, sorry... (I'm pretty new to LaTex)